# JavaScript not working when loaded in header view in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and Codeigniter. I am also using a Template system.

In the header view, I load both jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js and the paths are found as I can click and see the code when I do view-source.

In my controller, I have the following to generate the view:

```
$this->template->set_partial('header', 'layouts/admin_header');
$this->template->set_partial('footer', 'layouts/admin_footer');
$this->template->set_partial('sidebar', 'layouts/admin_sidebar');
$this->template->build('admin/category/order', $this->data);
```

In the header layout view, I have:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Now, in the order.php view, if I just have the following, the button doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').button();

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
  });  
});

</script>

<button class="btn" id="button" data-text-loading="Loading...">Press Me</button>
```

If I change the view to this, it does work (the only changed is that I repeated the bootstrap.min.js from the header into the actual view above the jQuery):

```
<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').button();

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).button('loading');
  });  
});

</script>

<button class="btn" id="button" data-text-loading="Loading...">Press Me</button>
```

If I view-source after the whole page is generated, the bootstrap.min.js is found twice, once in the header, and again directly above the button jQuery.

I can put other jQuery into this page and it works perfectly fine. It's only the Twitter Bootstrap javascript that has issues.

This is driving me absolutely nuts, does anyone know why it's doing this? I really do not want to have to add the bootstrap.min.js to each individual view...

Comment: What browser is this occurring in? This could potentially be related to how the Chrome 20 engine is rendering things now.

Comment: It's in Chrome but I just tried in Firefox and I'm getting the same result

Comment: Did you try setting the `type="text/javascript"` (or `type="application/javascript"` to be modern) on the bootstrap include ? Maybe it is required in the `<head>` but not in the `<body>`.

Comment: Do you have a web page available with this? Maybe its something else that is causing this.

Comment: No, I'm working on this locally. It'd take some work to get this on a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js loading after bootstrap.min.js. Apparently there's some conflict.

Comment: Yeah, I think that could have been solved by looking at the console errors. bootstrap.min.js probably was calling functions that were not instantiated yet by jquery-ui. order matters! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Declaring:

`<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Right before (in the same file, don't put it in the head tag since you are using codeigniter templating)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').button();

        $('#button').click(function() {
            $(this).button('loading');
        });
    });

</script>
```

This should work.